# How to change "metres" from "degrees" without change of location?

Tags: layers, units

I am working in QGIS (version 3.10). I know that in order to make certain distance analysis (in my case I want to do a heat map) a layer should have meters as units. Initially from the automatic SRC EPSG: 4326- WGS 84 I change my point layer' SRC to one set on metres (3857- WGS84/ Pseudo-Mercator). It does work in the sense the units do change to meters, however the points appear somewhere else. I tried to change the SRC of the project, start from scratch with the new SRC, different SRC combinations (using different SRCs for the project and/ or point layer) but just cannot get the units and the location both right.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you don't change the layer CRS but only the project CRS ("Project" menu > "Properties" > tab "CRS"). If you change CRS in the layer  without changing original coordinates, you will "mess up" the position of your points.

If you really want to get your layer with another CRS, you create a new layer with the new projection by right clicking on the layer tree name then "Export", then "Save Features As..." and change the CRS output.

This newly created layer will correctly "align" with other layers contrary to what you seem to have done/achieved at the moment.